# What HDMI to DVI adapters are high quality?

Tags: video-adapter, macos

When I bought my Mac mini Server (Mid 2011) it came with a HDMI to DVI adapter/dongle. Now I want to buy a similar, high quality, dongle for my retina Macbook Pro. I prefer a HDMI dongle because it keeps my Thunderbolt ports available. How can I determine quality so I'm not just shopping based on price?

[image: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3235]

from: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3235

And if not, what is a good alternative? I know about the [Belkin HDMI to DVI](http://store.apple.com/us/product/HA835ZM/A/belkin-hdmi-to-dvi-d-cable-2-m66-ft?fnode=51), but I dislike the long cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these adapters is available from eBay in the US at this link: [HDMI to DVI Adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/191282943181?lpid=82). Many more are available from other sellers.

Comment: Many such items on eBay do not fit the description "high quality". Per the original question, how does one know which ones are, and which ones aren't?

Comment: I would go with a brand name such as Belkin, Apple, Amazon, etc. I've had bad experiences with Monoprice adaptors which have miserable strain and torque (twisting) cable relief. There are many, many companies which make adaptors. Which ones are best? I dunno.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a dongle which attaches to my monitor and provides a `hdmi` port  http://au.element14.com/multicomp/1901117/series/dp/1428272

Note hdmi to digital DVI is a totally passive interface as they are pin compatible (although lacking sound support).

Answer (score 0):

Monoprice cables and accessories have a good reputation for quality at low prices. They have a [selection of HDMI to DVI adapters](http://www.monoprice.com/category?c_id=104&cp_id=10419&cs_id=1041902).